# VBA - How do I click at a given position without moving the mouse/cursor? (to ByPass Silverlight pop-up security message)

Tags: vba, silverlight, sendmessage

Good Day!

I have a code that could move the Mouse Cursor from a IE window and send a left mouse click.

```
Function MoveMouseCursor(ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, hwnd As Long)
If hwnd = 0 Then
    SetCursorPos X, Y
Else
    Dim lpPoint As POINTAPI
    lpPoint.X = X
    lpPoint.Y = Y
    ClientToScreen hwnd, lpPoint
    SetCursorPos lpPoint.X, lpPoint.Y

    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&
End If 
End Function
```

I am able to get the HWND of the IE window I wanted to send a mouse click.
What I wanted to do is to send a mouse click to the IE window without moving my mouse pointer so that I could still use my mouse even if the Macro is running.
So far while searching, I came up with this code but I think it is not yet working. Using API SendMessage I think is the better solution but I cant make it to work. Hope somebody can help me! :)

here is my code so far.

```
 Dim DaWord As Long
    DaWord = MakeDWord(IEWin.Width / 2, IEWin.Height / 2)
    Sleep 200
    SendMessage hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, ByVal DaWord
    Sleep 200
    SendMessage hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, ByVal DaWord

Private Function MakeDWord(ByVal LoWord As Integer, ByVal HiWord As Integer) As Long

MakeDWord = (HiWord * &H10000) Or (LoWord And &HFFFF&)

End Function
```

Comment: Let me ask you this: What are you trying to accomplish? Have you tried looking into the HTML page? You can query and receive data with html elements without resorting to clicking.

Comment: _Using API SendMessage I think is the better solution_ : I'd rather say no. In the Microsoft environment, with thousands of API for controlling every application and part of the system, there's **almost never** the need of using something "brutal" like sending keys or moving the mouse to automate something. Follow @JLILIAmen, disclose what you're trying to do because there's almost certainly a better solution.

Comment: Hi, @JLILIAmen. The one that I wanted to send a mouse click is a Silverlight pop-up security message which cannot be capture in HTML elements, the only way to close the pop-up is to send a left mouse click to the pop-up message.

Comment: Hi, @Matteo NNZ, I don't think I already tried all the possible solution but moving the mouse to the pop-up security message and send a mouse click on it do the job. But what I am about to try is to click on that pop-up security message without moving the mouse cursor.

Comment: Does this window comes with a process (I guess it must)? Are you able to open the task manager and identify the name of it? Cause if yes, you can terminate the process by querying the system processes rather than clicking with the mouse.

Comment: Well. If SliverLight does not have a com library, does it? If yes, he would be able to set all the alters display to off. ? What happens if you uninstall SliverLight?

Comment: @user3667320: Please edit your question and add the information about the sliverlight alert. Hopefully, someone who is more knowledgeable than I am can help you with that.

Comment: Hi @MatteoNNZ, the window come when I click the attach file button using macro. the Silverlight security message will pop up. unfortunately I cannot upload an image :( so that I can show you. It is not showing in Task Manager.

Comment: hi @JLILIAmen, I cannot uninstall the Silverlight as it is part of the webpage I am trying to automate.

Comment: When the security message pops up. Open your windows task manager and check if the security message is an actual error as precised by MatteoNZZ. If yes, and then you can kill it.

Comment: Try this: 1) Manually, get to the point where the SilverLight pop-up appears; 2) Open your Task Manager and go into the tab "Applications". Look for the task and right-click to find "Go to process"; 3) You will be redirect to the "Processes" tab. There, get the name of the process and note it somewhere. 4) Into your code, query the processes by that name and kill the process; it should work. Alternatively, can you provide us the webpage to have a look? This Silverlight must come from somewhere (probably front-end).

Comment: Hi @MatteoNNZ the Silverlight Pop-up does not appear in Task Manager.. this is an example of error pop-up I encounter [link](http://cutesoft.net/forum_uploads2/sshot-163.png)